# SSRS design list of content

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am new in SSRS Reporting services and I would like to know if its possible to create the reports

[SSRS Report image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHcrb.png)

We need one excel report to contain all the other reports connected to one SSRS Report.

I have many reports in SSRS. I need to create one report and it will contain all the data for each organization and create it as a package.

Could some one please suggest me how to do so?

Many thanks in advance.

Thank you!
Avinash

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do what you want using SSRS.

Sub reports is what you need to look at. They are pretty simple to set-up. Start reading here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-subreport-and-parameters-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

There are plenty of examples on how to implement them too, now you know what to search for.

If you get stuck you can come back with specific questions